# CSS gradual background change of a moving div?

Tags: css, background, css-animations, mousehover

What I am trying to achieve is this:

[image]

a coin (ring) sinking into the slot. Initially it is blue. when it enters the red background it becomes white. when it reaches the slot - it is gradually disappearing.

and this is what I have come up with so far:

```
  .circle {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(http://a5w.org/up/uploads/mike/2017-11-15/1510773962_red_square.png) no-repeat;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-position: 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 22;
}

.circle:hover {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-position: 0px -100px;
}

.rect {
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #666;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.slot{

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 666;
  background: #666;
  margin-top: 50px;

  height: 200px;
  width: 230px;
  border-top: solid 2px #333


}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y4fpyjsa/17/

This looks more like a hack though so I am wondering if there is a better solution, probably? Without moving backgrounds and extra layers.

Comment: so you don't have any issue as i see ? .. `better solution` is something relative, you mean what by better?

Comment: the solution with moving the background works but as an example. That would be rather inconvenient to apply this to the final project. Not flexible enough to say the less. Maybe there is a possibility to work with gradients...just stuck with this, seemingly easy, problem (((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 2 circles and play with z-index. One will be a part of the rect but hidden with `overflow:hidden` and will only be visible on hover when you increase its margin. The second one (the main one) will be hidden on hover below the rect because its low z-index.

With this trick you will *visually* have one circle with 2 different border colors and no need to change background.

```css
.circle {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border:40px solid red;
  background-position: 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-100px;
  z-index: 22;
}
.white {
  top:-200px;
  border:40px solid white;
  z-index:21
}


body:hover .circle {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.rect {
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #666;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  position:relative;
  z-index:500;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.slot {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 666;
  background: #666;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 230px;
  border-top: solid 2px #333;
  right:50%;
  margin-right:-115px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
</div>
<div class="slot">
</div>
<div class="rect">
<div class="circle white">
</div>
</div>
```

The only issue with this solution is that you have to make the hover effect on the container (here i used the body) as you cannot target one circle to move both of them.

Comment: woah, mate! Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!!
That  IS what I was looking for, really.

Comment: @Rossitten you're welcome ;) i let you find a better way for hover :) you put everything inside a container.